# Can I use "gksu" to became root for CLI operation?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, dpkg

I don't care if this is unsafe, because I'm only doing it as a programming exercise, but that's what I want to do:

I want to create a C program that, with the "system" command, will call dpkg and install some .deb files.

But, I want it to use something like gksu to ask for the password outside of the command line environment.

So, basically, I will double click my program and it will do for me:

1. Check if the .deb files are present
2. If not, use notify-send to tell the user there's a file missing
3. If they are all present, call a "gksu dpkg" thing to install the packages and use notify-send to tell when the packages are installed.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `gksu` for command-line/terminal operations, `gksu` is a *"GTK+ frontend for su and sudo"*, why not just use `sudo` directly?

Bash script would work easily on the command line. See `man bash` for info like

> test: test [expr]
>   Evaluate conditional expression.
>     -e FILE        True if file exists.
>     -f FILE        True if file exists and is a regular file.

so

```
#!/bin/bash
if test -f somefile.deb
then
    sudo dpkg -i somedebfile
else
    notify-send "somefile.deb is missing"
fi
```

Comment: I know, but it's something silly I want to do as a programming exercise. Nothing I would ever really use in life.